# Persisting timestamp field as Date or Long?

Tags: jpa, persistence, timestamp

I need a consensus on the practice of persisting timestamps, specifically on the pros & cons of using `java.util.Date` compared to using `long`.

Scope of this discussion:

- Performance
- Querying Flexibility (e.g. date range)
- Any hazards in coding and querying
- Portability (e.g. migration to other DB)

About myself:
I consider myself to be a beginner in JPA, dabbling in it once in a while, not being able to apply it into production level projects until now. In my current project, I commit myself to use ObjectDB (embedded) through JPA calls.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following class demonstrates 3 possible methods for persisting timestamps in JPA:

```
@Entity
public class Timestamps {
    private java.sql.Timestamp ts1;
    private @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP) java.util.Date ts2;
    private long ts3;
    :
}
```

Regarding performance and memory consumption, ts3 is a bit more efficient.

ts3 may be less convenient to use than ts1 and ts2 (in ObjectDB Database Explorer, reports, etc.).

Basic queries such as retrieval by date range are supported for all the three, but extracting date and time parts (YEAR, MONTH, etc.) in queries is not supported for ts3.

All these forms are expected to be portable.

ts1 and ts2 are practically equivalent.

More details are provided in the [ObjectDB manual](http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/entity/types#Date_and_Time_Temporal_Types_).

Comment: I guess Date wins on convenience and readability where queries were involved. Long is maybe applicable in raw data application e.g. scientific, medical where queries maybe rare or invoked post-collection e.g. report generation.

Answer (score 0):

In the documentation of java it looks like timestamp is closer related to java.util.date

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html

additionally if you care about the semantic of your code, a timestamp is a date.

Answer (score 0):

You should be aware about **java.sql.Timestamp**'s fact before using it:

*There are some classes in the Java platform libraries that do extend an instantiable
class and add a value component. For example, java.sql.Timestamp
extends java.util.Date and adds a nanoseconds field. The equals implementation
for Timestamp does violate symmetry and can cause erratic behavior if
Timestamp and Date objects are used in the same collection or are otherwise intermixed.
The Timestamp class has a disclaimer cautioning programmers against
mixing dates and timestamps. While you won’t get into trouble as long as you
keep them separate, there’s nothing to prevent you from mixing them, and the
resulting errors can be hard to debug. This behavior of the Timestamp class was a
mistake and should not be emulated. (Bloch, Effective Java, 2nd Ed.)*